# i had a problem while implementing tabs in android

Tags: android

hello i had four tabs as 
application starts with home selected diplaying some list,
after clicking on menu it displays menu items in list
after clicking on breakfast it displays a list of breakfast items
here while i am displaying i am unable to display the tabs
so please any one help me to keep the tabs till the end

Answer (score 0):

you have to use ActivityGroup to keep the tab displayed. Check out this guide: http://united-coders.com/nico-heid/use-android-activitygroup-within-tabhost-to-show-different-activity